# Are there any useful extensions in vscode for auto importing angular Interface (eg: ActivatedRoute)?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I use vscode to do a demo of angular. Which plugins can be used to auto import Angular Interface?

I have already installed `Auto Import` & `Auto Import - ES6, TS, JSX, TSX` extensions. But they didn't work.

I expect when I type `ActivatedRoute`， it will be automatically imported.

Comment: It should have this functionality built in, when you type in ActivatedRoute, do you see a dropdown list appear as you type?? If so press tab on ActivatedRoute and it will auto import. It wont auto import unless you do that. You can't just type it in.

Comment: there doesn't appear a dropdown list as I type `ActivatedRoute`  ,but when i type `@Input` the list appears and `Input` can be auto import .

Comment: Try restarting vscode

Comment: I haved tried serval times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install auto import extension in vs code

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport

You can also install

> Angular Extension Pack

from the extension tab in the VS CODE, this package also provides the auto import functionality.